# R studio crashes while merge 2 data sets

Tags: r

I am new to R , i am struggling to merge two data set. R studio crashes , i am using R in mac with 8gb of RAM. my data set are of 8 mb & 12 mb.

my code is :

```
data1 <- read.csv("~/Downloads/1987.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
View(data1)
data2 <- read.csv("~/Downloads/1988.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
View(data2)
merg_tab <- merge(data1,data2)
```

after 5-10 min R studio crashes.

Comment: Have you tried selecting small subsets of your data sets and seeing if it completes then?

Comment: When you don't use the `by` option in `merge`, it uses all of the like names between the two data sets. This may or may not be what you want and may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `fread()` function from the `data.table` package instead of the R native `read.csv` function.

```
require(data.table)

data1 <- fread("~/Downloads/1987.csv")
data2 <- fread("~/Downloads/1988.csv")
```

You can then merge the two sets using the `merge` function by specifying the shared key column(s) (say column_X):

```
merg_tab <- merge(data1, data2, by = "column_X")
```

Comment: The `merge()` function has the same "by" option for data frames as well. The point is that when using `data.table::fread()` to import the data, you will have a `data.table` object instead of a `data.frame`, and calling `merge()` will be executed by the `merge()` function provided by the data.frame library which will indeed tend not to crash when `base::merge()` would.